# How do I make 6 elastic panes (1 header, 5 panes) with default width and height using Angular UI.Layout?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

According to Angular UI.Layout's guideline (contributing.md), I'm asking here but sorry for my newbie question and my bad English.

I want to make 6 elastic panes like this.

[image: 6 elastic panes]

But I found [an issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-layout/issues/189) that Angular UI.Layout doesn't support to set an initial height to a header.
So if the problem still persists, at least I want to make 5 elastic panes without header (I'm planning to move the header to outside `ui-layout` directives).

How do I make these panes?

Comment: I found mistakes in the image. "(45% including header)" is wrong. "(45% including sidebar)" is correct.

Comment: did you manage to do this?

Comment: @JoãoPereira well, style was changed so angular-ui is not used...

Answer (score 0):

It's just a suggestion to make all without *angular-ui*

See this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/NSJ9vQZZltLmZRONc2ds?p=preview

```
 <div style="background:red; position:absolute; top:0; height:25px;width:100%;"></div>
 <div style="background:blue; position:absolute; bottom:0; top:25px; width:10%;"></div>
 <div style="position:absolute; left:10%; bottom:0; top:25px; width:100%;">
      <div style="background:green;float:right; width:50%;height:50%"></div>
      <div style="background:yellow;float:left; width:50%;height:50%"></div>
      <div style="background:purple;float:right; width:50%;height:50%"></div>
      <div style="background:gray;float:left; width:50%;height:50%"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm using Angular UI because I need shrink/expand feature by dragging border.